# Get the value of an element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my html snippet:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
  <td><h6 id="{{$index}}">{{row.inventory_serialno}}</h6></td>
</tr>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inventory_serialno">SL No:</label>
  <input class="form-control" value="//I need the value of h6 here//" id="inventory_serialno" placeholder="Enter serial number">
</div>
```

Goal:

1. Get the value of an element inside `ng-repeat` (In this case the 'h6' tag value of each row)
2. Use that corresponding value to autofill the value of respective text box input present in each row.

The input text box is out of the `ng-repeat` scope.
For some reason i cant access the value of the h6 tag if i do this (gives a value null)

```
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML; //or even text()
```

Weirdly i noticed the above JavaScript code runs fine on the browser console but not on my script (which means its something to do with the angular element generation time.. May be i'm accessing it before it even got generated).

Nonetheless can someone please shed some light on the solution. Thanks in advance.

******** Updated with controller code *****

```
app.controller('InventoryCtrl', function ($scope) {

    var x = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML; // giving a null value
    console.log(x); 

    $scope.rowCollection = [{
        id: 100,
        inventory_serialno: 'HW13FGL'
      }, {
        id: 101,
        inventory_serialno: 'SM123GH'
      }, {
        id: 102,
        inventory_serialno: 'LK90100'
      }];
});
```

Comment: Don't start an id with a number

Comment: Share your controller code where you're trying to access it

Comment: I think you should have **ng-repeat="row in rowCollection track by $index"** if you want to access $index.

Comment: Hey camden...thanks for the suggestion, but i have used that too. still had the same result.

Comment: @Huangism - I used an integer just to simplify the code.  I have tried that too. Tried using `id="elem{{$index}}"`. Still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
<input value="{{rowCollection[2].inventory_serialno}}" />
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13004/)

However I would place the input inside the `ng-repeat` to keep it clean, and achieve the layout you like inside a big wrapper, something like this:

```
<div class="grid" ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
  <div class="col">
    <h6 id="{{$index}}">{{row.inventory_serialno}}</h6>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
      <form>
        <input value="{{row.inventory_serialno}}"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need an input for each item, use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tony, but this would always retrieve the 3rd item from the array and update the value. Each row will have a separate input box. Like i said i need to get the corresponding values to the respective input boxes.

Comment: Oh I see - could you not just place a input box inside the ng-repeat then?

Comment: No actually according to the template i want to achieve, i want to populate the values on a separate div corresponding to each row elements. If on the same row then i could easily feed the value from the array directly but thats not what i want to achieve.

Comment: ok, my suggestion would be to place the input inside a bigger ng-repeat, and achieve the layout you wish that way.

Comment: I would definitely try that out. Thanks for the suggestion buddy